# How to get Amazon's discounted price?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm using ItemSearch Amazon API. It works fine for most cases; however, when Amazon has a discount, **it doesn't show the discounted price they show on Amazon, it returns the old original price**.

For example for [this](http://amzn.to/2yGa4VH) item, Amazon's discounted price is **$37.50**. However, the API just returns the original price: **$44.99**.

The **Offers** section doesn't help either (it has other sellers' offers, not Amazon's).

Any thoughts anyone?

Here is the API call for your convenience (fill up the {} fields):

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId={}&AssociateTag={}&Condition=New&Keywords=887961219319&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes%2CLarge%2COffers%2CReviews&SearchIndex=All&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp={}&Signature={}
```

Answer (score 2):

After almost about a week of digging and investigation, it turns out I had to remove the "**condition**" field from the request! After that, I was able to get the the price displayed on Amazon.com properly! (using the filed Item.Offers.Offer.OfferListing.Price.Amount).

**Reason**: it seems Amazon displays what they call as "*Buy Box Winner*" price if it exists, or the lowest possible offer. To get this value returned in the response, you'd have to remove the Condition field in addition to the MerchantId as well. More details [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Offers.html).

Jeez Amazon! I hope someone finds this useful!